# Explicit formula for Riemann curvatures with all indices lowered

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I know that $R^a_{bcd}=\partial_c\Gamma^a_{db}-\partial_d\Gamma^a_{cb}+\Gamma^a_{cf}\Gamma^f_{db}-\Gamma^a_{df}\Gamma^f_{cb}$. But I found that for $R_{abcd}=g_{ae}R^e_{bcd}$, the following formula holds.

\begin{align} R_{abcd}=\frac12\left(g_{ad,bc}-g_{bd,ac}-g_{ac,bd}+g_{bc,ad}\right)-g_{ef}\left(\Gamma_{ac}^e\Gamma_{bd}^f-\Gamma_{ad}^e\Gamma_{bc}^f\right)
\end{align}

I think the Levi-Civita connection is assumed for this formula. How can I derive this formula for all indices lowered from $R^a_{bcd}$ above? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You will not need to look at the second two terms and you should plug in $\Gamma^k_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_ig_{jl}+\partial_{j}g_{il}-\partial_{l}g_{ij})$.

Comment: The second two terms are actually what bugs me. The summation is different from just multiplying the metric...also how should I deal with the derivatives of the inverse metric?

Comment: Hmm, I did not do the exercise actually, maybe I am wrong about the second two terms... Note that $g^{ij}g_{jk}=\delta^i_k$ is constant. Take derivatives of this expression and you will find expressions for the derivative of the inverse metric.